# Lowercase everything except when between brackets

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following string:

```
LoReM {FOO} IPSUM dolor {BAR} Samet {fooBar}
```

I'm looking for a way to lowercase everything - except what is between {brackets} should be ignored. So the desired output is:

```
lorem {FOO} ipsum dolor {BAR} samet {fooBar}
```

In another topic @stema pointed to https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php to achieve something like this, but I dont understand how:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~\{.*?\}~', function ($match) {
  return strtolower($match[1]);
}, 'LoReM {FOO} IPSUM dolor {BAR} Samet {fooBar}');
```

This returns only the string without the bracketed {tags}, and not even lowercased. Who can help me solve this? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: There is no `$match[1]` with your pattern (only 0). Next to that you don't want to lowercase the match but everything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to let regex ignore everything between brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219072/how-to-let-regex-ignore-everything-between-brackets)

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
~(?:^|})(.*?)(?:\{|$)~
```

**explanation:**

```
~           : delimiter
  (?:       : start non capture group
    ^|}     : begin of string or }
  )         : end of group
  (         : start capture group #1
    .*?     : any number of any char. non greedy
              (ie: all char outside of {})
  )         : end of group
  (?:       : start non capture group
    \{|$    : { or end of string
  )         : end of group
~           : delimiter
```

Answer (score 3):

Your expression must catch the other parts:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~^.*?{|}.*?{|}.*?$}~', function ($match) {
  return strtolower($match[0]);
}, 'LoReM {FOO} IPSUM dolor {BAR} Samet {fooBar}');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `preg_replace_callback()` is probably the best method.  You just need to fix the regular expression to be this instead:

```
~(^|\})(.*?)(\{|$)~
```

And then return this:

```
return $match[1] . strtolower($match[2]) . $match[3];
```

Comment: @hakre: It handles that case just fine?

Comment: @drrcknsln: Not if you actually use upper-case letters in the original string: `Tree } Makes Me Wonder {FOO} { Sick String` - http://codepad.viper-7.com/x1Kihk

Comment: @hakre: Ah, I think I see what you meant now.  It doesn't handle `^([^{]*)\}` and `\{([^}]*)$` cases properly.

Comment: drrcknlsn What black magic this is! Could you explain to me how it works? I don't understand how only $match[2] is lowercased, but then the words are being put in the right places back into the string? @hakre - such a case will never happen. I can say with certainty that all {tags} have an opening and closing bracket (with no brackets therein).

Comment: @Reveller: Basically, this regex ignores what's between `{` and `}`.  We aren't concerned with replacing that, because we want to leave it as-is.  Instead we find/replace the text that's between `}` and `{`, or beginning of line and `{`, or `}` and end of line.  In other words, we leave the `{tags}` alone, and match everything around them.

Answer (score 2):

You want to match all characters except those within `{}`. Then replace the match with an `strtolower` of it.

To do so, you need to create a pattern that matches everything but the bracket-pairs:

```
~(?:{\w+}(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|[^{}]+~
```

This will skip (and drop) all bracket pairs but match everything else that is not a bracket character (`{` or `}`. You can then just lowercase the match using your callback function:

```
$str = '{LoReM {FOO} IPSUM { dolor {BAR} Samet {fooBar} Tou}Louse';

$out = preg_replace_callback('~(?:{\w+}(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|[^{}]+~', function($m)
    {return strtolower($m[0]);}, $str)
    ;

echo $out;
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HgeEUk), Output:

```
{lorem {FOO} ipsum { dolor {BAR} samet {fooBar} tou}louse
```

As the example shows, non-associated brackets aren't a burden. This pattern also specifies how the bracket pairs should be written, `\w` stands for any word character, you can replace it with any character-class that full-fills your needs if it's not fitting (e.g. in your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219072/how-to-let-regex-ignore-everything-between-brackets)).

This is actually pretty similar to a question that has already been answered: [**How to let regex ignore everything between brackets?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219072/how-to-let-regex-ignore-everything-between-brackets) - it's practically an exact duplicate which I now saw after answering more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
$input = 'LoReM {FOO} IPSUM dolor {BAR} Samet {fooBar}';
preg_match_all('~\{.*?\}~', $input, $matches);
$output = strtolower($input);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
  $output = str_replace(strtolower($match), $match, $output);
}
```

Comment: This has a lot of side-effects. It will only work by chance, not by design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) with the PREG_REPLACE_EVAL modifier as in:

```
$string  = 'LoReM {FOO} IPSUM dolor {BAR} Samet {fooBar}';
$pattern = '/(?<![[:word:]{])[[:word:]]*?(?![[:word:]}])/e';
echo preg_replace($pattern, 'strtolower($0)', $string);
```

Everything that the pattern matches is then replaced by evaluating `strtolower()` on the match. If you want to understand the regex it's easiest to start in the middle, (I've separated the blocks with spaces for readability)

```
(?<![[:word:]{]) [[:word:]]*? (?![[:word:]}])
^                ^            ^
|                |            |
|                +-- match any amount of word characters (alphanums)
|                             |
+-- that are not preceded by a word character or {
                              |
                              +-- and are not followed by a word character or }

Where word characters are alphanumeric characters and underscores.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of problem that a REGEX has a lot of trouble with. A better solution would be to write a parser that reads character by charcter and can switch state.

- Start in lowercase mode. Output each read character in lower case.
- If a `{` character is read in lowercase mode, switch to uppercase mode.
- if a `}` character is read in uppercase mode, switch to lowercase mode.

Keep in mind that it will be more complicated if you want to handle nested braces.