# JS extract all text outside the brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract the text outside the square/round brackets.

`"WALL COLOR (IS HERE) [SHERWIN-WILLIAMS]"`

The expected result is `"WALL COLOR"` and not `"WALL COLOR "`

I have tried with

```
"WALL COLOR (IS HERE) [SHERWIN-WILLIAMS]".match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[0]
```

Whether a [0] is needed to get result as string instead array.

Comment: Use index `1` for string result

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219072/how-to-let-regex-ignore-everything-between-brackets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your brackets are balanced and there is no escaping etc, It will be easier to do it via `.replace`. You may use this `.replace` method to remove all strings that are `[...]` and `(...)` surrounded with optional whitespaces on both sides.

```
str = str.replace( /\s*(?:\[[^\]]*\]|\([^)]*\))\s*/g, "" )
//=> "WALL COLOR"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9m0XVe/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespace
- `(?:`: Start non-capturing group

  - `\[[^\]]*\]`: Match text that is `[...]`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\([^)]*\)`: Match text that is `(...)`
- `)`: End non-capturing group
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespace

---

PS: If you want to allow escaped brackets in your input i.e. `WALL COLOR (IS \(escaped\) HERE) [SHERWIN-\[WILL\]IAMS]` then use this bit more complex regex:

```
/\s*(?:\[[^\\\]]*(?:\\.[^\\\]]*)*\]|\([^\\)]*(?:\\.[^\\)]*)*\))\s*/g
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/9m0XVe/2)