# Regex to ignore data between brackets

Tags: python, regex

I replace characters `{` , `}` , `:` , `,` with an empty string using below:

This code :

```
s = "\":{},"
print(s)
print(re.sub(r'\"|{|}' , "",s))
```

prints:

```
":{},
:,
```

which is expected.

I'm attempting to modify the regex to ignore everything between open and closed brackets. So for the string `"\":{},[test,test2]"` just `:,[test,test2]` should be returned.

How to modify the regex such that data contained between `[` and `]` is not applied by the regex.

I tried using:

```
s = "\":{},[test1, test2]"
print(s)
print(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z {}]+\"|{|}' , "",s))
```

(src: [How to let regex ignore everything between brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219072/how-to-let-regex-ignore-everything-between-brackets))

None of the `,` values are replaced .

Comment: For your example won't `re.sub(r'[{}"]', '', s)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the `{`, `}`, `,` and `"` not inside square brackets, you can use

```py
re.sub(r'(\[[^][]*])|[{}",]', r'\1', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5sAYo3/4). Note you can add more chars to the character set,  `[{}"]`. If you need to add a hyphen, make sure it is the last char in the character set. Escape `\`, `]` (if not the first, right after `[`) and `^` (if it comes first, right after `[`).

*Details*:

- `(\[[^][]*])` - Capturing group 1: a `[...]` substring
- `|` - or
- `[{}",]` - a `{`, `}`, `,` or `"` char.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sGlpwP) using your sample input:

```py
import re
s = "\":{},[test1, test2]"
print( re.sub(r'(\[[^][]*])|[{}",]', r'\1', s) )
## => :[test1, test2]
```

Comment: thanks, I wish to also replace any ',' outside the [ ]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your brackets are balanced/unescaped, you may use this regex with a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that matched character is not inside `[...]`:

```sh
>>> import re
>>> s = "\":{},[test1,test2]"
>>> print (re.sub(r'[{}",](?![^[]*\])', '', s))
:[test1,test2]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OYl0te/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[{}",]`: Match one of those character inside `[...]`
- `(?![^[]*\])`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a `]` ahead of without matching any `[` in between, in other words matched character is not inside `[...]`