# How to remove whitespaces in a string except from between certain elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, removing-whitespace

I have a string similar to (the below one is simplified):

```
"  word=       {his or her}      whatever  "
```

I want to delete every whitespace except between {}, so that my modified string will be:

```
"word={his or her}whatever"
```

lstrip or rstrip doesn't work of course. If I delete all whitespaces the whitespaces between {} are deleted as well. I tried to look up solutions for limiting the replace function to certain areas but even if I found out it I haven't been able to implement it. There are some stuff with regex (I am not sure if they are relevant here) but I haven't been able to understand them.

EDIT: If I wanted to except the area between, say {} and "", that is:

if I wanted to turn this string:

```
"  word=       {his or her} and "his or her"      whatever  "
```

into this:

```
"word={his or her}and"his or her"whatever"
```

What would I change

`re.sub(r'\s+(?![^{]*})', '', list_name)` into?

Comment: This is typically adressed by using regular expressions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66429357/regex-to-ignore-data-between-brackets

Answer (score 1):

See instead going arround `re` you can replace uisng `string.replace`. Which will be much more easier and less complex when you playing around strings. Espacillay when you have multiple substitutions you end up bigger `regex`.

```
st ="  word=       {his or her}      whatever  "
st2="""  word=       {his or her} and "his or her"      whatever  """

new = " ".join(st2.split())
new = new.replace("= ", "=").replace("} ", "}").replace('" ' , '"').replace(' "' , '"')
print(new)
```

Some outputs

**Example 1 output**

```
word={his or her}whatever
```

**Example 2 output**

```
word={his or her}and"his or her"whatever
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use by **replace**

```
def remove(string):
    return string.replace(" ", "")

string = 'hell o whatever'
print(remove(string)) // Output: hellowhatever
```