# Exclude any digits from match but keep digits within brackets

Tags: python, regex

**string**: `abc keyword1 ddd 111 ddd (ddd 99/ddd) 1 ddd (ddd) ddd 11 ddd keyword2 abc`

**regex**: `re.compile(r'(?:keyword1)(.*)(?:keyword2)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)`

**goal**: exclude all digits except the ones within brackets from match

**desired output**: `'ddd ddd (ddd 99/ddd) ddd (ddd) ddd ddd'`

approach1: Any digit within brackets is **always** 99 but the digits outside of brackets can also be 99. That is why i could also remove every digit from matching, except 99 and subsequently use not regex to remove the remaining 99s outside of brackets?!

approach2: match `ddd` (basically everything including `99`s) except all other digits using some variant of the help below. I played with the `(\([^)]*\)|\S)*` around but failed prob because its java :D

**Question**: Which approach makes sense? How can i modify my regex to reach my goal?

**related help**
[Exclude strings within parentheses from a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285510/exclude-strings-within-parentheses-from-a-regular-expression)
`(\([^)]*\)|\S)*`
where one balanced set of parentheses is treated as if it were a single character, and so the regex as a whole matches a single word, where a word can contain these parenthesized groups.

Comment: Do you mean to get any digit chunks inside parentheses? As with `\d+(?=[^()]*\))` (assuming all parentheses are paired in your strings)?

Comment: Yes, i want to exclude any digits (represented by the `1`s) but include the `99/` chunk in my match as it would be lost if i simply remove any digits from the string

Comment: Then, do you mean you want `re.findall(r'\b99/\d+(?=[^()]*\))', text)`?

Comment: Maybe you can include what exactly would be your desired result? Also, you are matching between keywords, does that mean that 'ddd' is a keyword and you are looking for digits between those?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/xPuJY2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any additional packages, you can use a two step approach: get the string between keywords and then remove all digit chunks that are not inside parentheses:

```py
import re
s = "abc keyword1 ddd 111 ddd (ddd 99/ddd) 1 ddd (ddd) ddd 11 ddd keyword2 abc"
m = re.search(r'keyword1(.*?)keyword2', s, re.I | re.S)
if m:
    print( re.sub(r'(\([^()]*\))|\s*\d+', r'\1', m.group(1)) )

## => ddd ddd (ddd 99/ddd) ddd (ddd) ddd ddd
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xPuJY2).

**Notes**:

- `keyword1(.*?)keyword2` extracts all contents between `keyword1` and `keywor2` into Group 1
- `re.sub(r'(\([^()]*\))|\s*\d+', r'\1', m.group(1))` removes any digit chunks preceded with optional whitespace from the Group 1 value while keeping all strings between `(` and `)` intact.